# group concat and in clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, group-concat, where-in

Hi have two tables named  Roles and jobs respectivly[image: jobs table structure]

[image: Roles table structure]

and when in  run the below query

```
SELECT job_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(roles_title) from jobs left join roles on roles_id in (roles) group by job_id
```

[image: Result i got]

Expected Result

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Job_id</td>
    <td>Roles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Admin,acc & test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>acc& test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The answer here is to normalize the data,while the answer might work if you have many rows it will be slower than a snail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` in join Clause.

```
SELECT job_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(roles_title SEPARATOR '&')
     from jobs
      left join roles on FIND_IN_SET(roles_id,roles)
GROUP BY job_id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am getting only single row

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot group by.. Please c heck now